# Dynamically creating number of tags in influxdb-java API point to insert a point in influxDB

Tags: java, influxdb

I am trying to insert the oracle data into the influxdb using influxdb-java API.

I want to write a generic code to insert the data into influx based on my SQL query output fields.

Currently i am using switch and making multiple cases based on number of attributes i get from the query.
Code for reference:

```
switch (columnLength) {
case 1:
    sotPoint = Point.measurement(measurementName)   
            .time(System.currentTimeMillis(),TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .tag("source", "SOT")
            .tag(attributes[0],rsObj.getString(attributes[0]))
            .addField("recordcount", 1)
            .build();
    break;
case 2: 
    sotPoint = Point.measurement(measurementName)   
            .time(System.currentTimeMillis(),TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .tag("source", "SOT")
            .tag(attributes[0],rsObj.getString(attributes[0]))
            .tag(attributes[1],rsObj.getString(attributes[1]))
            .addField("recordcount", 1)
            .build();
    break;
default: System.out.println("Invalid column length");
}
```

Is there any way to dynamically create the tags field separately and while creating the point just add those fields in that point?

I am using influxdb-java API 2.2 version

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.influxdb</groupId>
<artifactId>influxdb-java</artifactId>
<version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve above goal using builder object:

```
    Builder builder=Point.measurement(measurementName).time(date,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).tag("source", source);

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : tagMap.entrySet()) {
        builder.tag(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
    }

    for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : filedMap.entrySet()) {
        builder.addField(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
    }

    builder.addField("recordcount", 1);
    point=builder.build();
```